# TestFlight Beta has expired

Tags: ios, testflight

I uploaded a new build to AppStoreConnect. I was able to test it through TestFlight.

I sent the build to review, it was approved. Then when I tried to open the test app on my device and got the above error:

[image]

The status on TestFlight seems to be "Ready for Submit, expires in 86 days".

I tried to remove the app, and reinstall it from TestFlight. Then I got this:

[image]

Restarting the phone, or trying to install it from a different device leads to the same problem.

Why does that happen? Is it an Apple-side bug?

What is the workaround for this issue?

Comment: As of December 8, 2022, for those of you viewing this question, many people are experiencing this over the past day. It's Apple-side bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in TestFlight and/or iOS.

It happens when you upload a new version with automatic updates. Installing the app manually seems to be just fine.

**Consider downgrading to a previous build and then manually updating it or uploading and installing a new build. Both options should solve this issue.**

It started to happen in late October 2022, and it is still happening to our builds as of November 2022.

Comment: Hey @forschter thanks for your answer. So in my case, since I don't have any other available builds, do I will have to upload a new one in order to test it?

Comment: IMO Apple TestFlight and AppStoreConnect are so bugged and deprecated... IDK how Apple, the top company on Earth, has such a bad CI/CD flow.

Comment: Uploading and installing a new build solved the issue. Still, not that convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload a new version onto test flight or add a new app directly with your mac so that it does not use testflight at all.

Comment: Adding a new build to TestFlight does *not* solve the issue unless it's installed manually.